# Using a 'not in' query inside of a check constraint in SQL

Tags: sql, db2, constraints

I have two tables, one of student and one of staff that look as such:

```
create table student (
id int not null primary key
)
create table staff (
id int not null primary key
)
```

I want the id in each to be unique. I know this isn't how it should be in production but I'm just trying to see why my check constraint doesn't work and I'm using a simpler example to explain.

I then alter the tables to include the check as follows:

```
alter table student add constraint not_staff check (id not in (select id from staff))
alter table staff add constraint not_student check (id not in (select id from student))
```

These checks seem to be invalid.

My question is whether we're allowed to have these kinds of SQL statements inside of a check constraint. If so, why is the above constraint invalid and how would I go about fixing it.

Thanks!

Comment: Create a user-defined function that does the check, and call it from the table check constraint. Alternatively you could use a database trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use queries in a check constraint in Db2. Refer to the description of the [CREATE TABLE](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-create-table) statement.

> **CHECK (check-condition)**
> Defines a check constraint. The search-condition must be true or unknown for every row of the table.
> **search-condition**
> The search-condition has the following restrictions:
> ...
>
> - The search-condition cannot contain any of the following (SQLSTATE 42621):
>
>   - Subqueries

The easiest way to achieve your goal is not to create constraints, but create a sequence and use it in before triggers on both tables.